# How can I make a Spinner only by java?

Tags: java, android, view, spinner, android-spinner

I tried with the following code, it runs but i don't see any thing...

```
   Spinner spv = new Spinner(context);

   String[] s = {"Normal","Italic","Bold"};     

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (context, 0, s);
   spv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How could i do it?

Comment: Why are you passing 0 as second argument for the adapter? Try to specify a layout resource like `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` for example.

Comment: And then add spv to your Layout using addView() method

Comment: In addition to both of those, `context` should be an `Activity`.

Comment: I can't use a resource layout because it should be make dynamically. However i already added the spinner on my parent view... I also tried to put the id of a TextView dynamically made as second parameter. The context isn't a problem because i show also other view by it...

Comment: Why you can't use a resource layout? Without a layout for spinner item your spinner item will not be visible